# Unsuccessfull call of array of abstract type

Tags: types, constructor, julia

I am trying to use to its best parametrization and types in Julia. 
I have a constructor which have for arguments an array of `T` and an array of `Interval{T,Bound{T},Bound{T}}` where `T` is a real Type and `Bound` is an abstract type from which OpenBound an NullBound are derived.

However when I try to call this constructor I get the following error:

```
   ERROR: MethodError: no method matching 
   HyperParameters(::Array{Float64,1}, 
   ::Array{Interval{Float64,OpenBound{Float64},NullBound{Float64}},1})
   Closest candidates are:
   HyperParameters(::Array{T<:Real,1}, ::Array{Interval{T<:Real,A,B} where 
   B<:Bound{T<:Real} where A<:Bound{T<:Real},1}) where T<:Real
```

While this does not happen for a constructor not using arrays (just `T` and `Interval{T,Bound{T},Bound{T}}`). I am using Julia 0.6.2. Any idea on how to solve this? Thanks!

Théo

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that types in Julia are invariant. A simpler example of your problem would be that `Vector{Vector{Int}}` is not a subtype of `Vector{AbstractVector{Int}}` although  `Vector{Int}` is subtype of `AbstractVector{Int}`. However `Vector{Vector{Int}}` is a subtype of `Vector{<:AbstractVector{Int}}`.

Therefore the solution to your problem is:

```
julia> abstract type Bound{T} end

julia> struct OpenBound{T} <: Bound{T} end

julia> struct NullBound{T} <: Bound{T} end

julia> struct Interval{T,A,B} end

julia> HyperParameters(::Vector{T}, ::Vector{Interval{T,A,B}}) where {B<:Bound{T}, A<:Bound{T}} where T<:Real = "OK"
HyperParameters (generic function with 1 method)

julia> x = [1.0]
1-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0

julia> y = [Interval{Float64, OpenBound{Float64}, NullBound{Float64}}()]
1-element Array{Interval{Float64,OpenBound{Float64},NullBound{Float64}},1}:
 Interval{Float64,OpenBound{Float64},NullBound{Float64}}()

julia> HyperParameters(x, y)
"OK"
```

Unfortunately you have not posted your definitions of types (which I would recommend you to do in the future) so I have to use artificial ones here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. On top of solving the problem, I understand a lot more how types are working!